# AppleScript: How to reload a Safari window without bring the window to the foreground while I am in other Desktop space

Tags: applescript

I want to write an AppleScript to achieve a simple task. That is, I open a Safari window on Desktop 1 and automatically reload the browser every 30 minutes while I do my daily work on Desktop 2.

Here is my script:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            keystroke "r" using {command down}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

This script works. However, whenever the script is executed, my current Desktop 2 will be brought back to Desktop 1. It is distracting to my workflow.

Is there any way to just let Safari to reload in the background without bring Safari window to foreground on Desktop 1?

I have done a couple of searches; many of them say I should not use "activate" in my script. I tried that but then the script will just do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply get the **URL** of **document 1**, then tell Safari to set the **URL** of **document 1** to that URL.

The effect is the page will reload. Without bringing Safari to the front or jumping to Safari while you are in another space.

```
    tell application "Safari"
    set docUrl to URL of document 1

    set URL of document 1 to docUrl
end tell
```

---

Also a simple on idle handler and saved as an Application (Stay open checked) that will run every 1 minute but not when Safari is fronmost. i.e when you are actually using it.

```
on idle

    set frontApp to name of application (path to frontmost application as text)

    if frontApp is not equal to "Safari" then
        tell application "Safari"
            set docUrl to URL of document 1

            set URL of document 1 to docUrl
        end tell

    end if
    return 60
end idle
```

Comment: Say, I am working all day on Desktop 2. I will let Safari reload on its own on Desktop 1 every 30 min. Whenever the script is executed, my Desktop 2 will be brought back to Desktop 1. For once, it is okay. However, it can be very annoying to shift the Desktop back and forth throughout the day. Therefore, I am looking for a better way to let Safari to reload on the background on its own.

Comment: Which is what the Applescript in my answer does??

Comment: The URL is dynamically changing everyday. Therefore, fixing it to a variable means I have to manually change the variable every day. It will be very inconvenient for me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the code. It is not hardcoding any URL. It is getting the current URL and reloading it. The same as what would happen with a reload from the Menu

Comment: My apology.

Your code does what I want. I was mucking up your code with mine.

You solved my problem!

Simple and elegant, excellent!

Comment: We have all been there, No prob. :)